# Doxygen for Python: How to generate documentation for nested functions

Tags: python, doxygen, nested-function

I am documenting my Python code using Doxygen. The code makes use of Pythons capability of defining nested functions.

So I have documented them as if they were "normal" functions and set `EXTRACT_ALL=YES`.

But still, the nested functions cannot be found anywhere. Is there a way to make Doxygen do that?

(Doxygen version 1.8.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to access nested functions so im sure it just doesnt document it

```
 def wrapper():
    def nested(a,b,c):
        return a+b+c
    return nested(1,2,3)

 #a user can call wrapper()
 print wrapper()
 #but there is no way to call nested
 print nested(7,7,7) #ERROR!!!
```

since a user cannot call it why would you document it?

(really this is just a comment that was too long to post as a comment)

Comment: I want to document it because I want to provide full, nicely formatted documentation of my code for future developers and it would've been nice if Doxygen included it in its output

Comment: Personally, I think it's a very important and valid point in answering the question.

Comment: @Paddre well I expect you are perhaps one of a very very small minority that wants this functionality.  and lucky for you Doxygen is an opensource project so you can simply branch it and add that functionality (fair warning it is probably more work than this is worth)